# Django: data from Views.py not displaying in HTML page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My home.html in div where I called the { data } to display in HTML

```
<div id= "main">
    <h1> DATA SCRAPPER</h1>
    <h2>Header Data from html Page</h2>
    { data }
</div>
```

The local host shows
[image]

But in terminal it is showing the scrapped data

Views.py where

```
def home(request):
    soup= None
    URL = 'https://www.abc.html'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.h1.text)
    head=soup.h1.text

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data': head})
```

Comment: **Typo:** It needs to be `{{ data }}` not `{ data }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing some curly braces.

You need:

```
{{ data }}
```

not

```
{ data }
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying variable data you have to use double bracket

```
{{data}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>code </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1> data </h1>
<h2> header data from html </h2>
{{data}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```